# How to set up different headers/footers for each page with TCPDF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am trying to set up different footers for each page with TCPDF. I am currently using a custom header and footer, but I haven't figured out how to set different footers for each page. Is this possible?

```
public function Footer() {

    $this->SetTextColor(168,163,163);

    // Position at 15 mm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-17);
    // Set font
    $this->SetFont('roboto', 'N', 10);

    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Something', 0, false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

    $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES."logo_example.jpg";
    $this->Image($image_file, 96, 272, 15, '', 'JPG', '', 'C', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);

    // Page number
    $this->Cell(12, 10, 'página '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a condition for example based on the page number:

```
if ($this->getAliasNumPage() == "1")
  $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Something only on the first page', 0, false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
```